# Is it possible to index only the matched log lines of grok in Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I'm having a log file, which actually has `INFO`s' and `ERROR`s. So I tried to match only the needful `INFO`s by using the **grok** filter. So [this](http://pastebin.com/HAzCRD0Z) is how my log lines look like. Few of them from the file.

And this is how my `grok` look like in my *logstash* conf:

```
grok {
        patterns_dir => ["D:/elk_stack_for_ideabiz/elk_from_chamith/ELK_stack/logstash-5.1.1/bin/patterns"]
        match => { 
            "message" => [
                "^TID\: \[0\] \[AM\] \[%{LOGTIMESTAMPTWO:logtimestamp}]%{REQUIREDDATAFORAPP:app_message}",
                "^TID\: \[0\] \[AM\] \[%{LOGTIMESTAMPTWO:logtimestamp}]%{REQUIREDDATAFORRESPONSESTATUS:response_message}"
            ]   
        }
    }
```

The pattern seems to be working fine. I could provide the `pattern` if required.

*I've got two questions*. One is I wanted only the *grok* matched lines to be sent to the index, and prevent `Logstash` from indexing the non-matched ones and the second is to prevent `Logstash` from showing the **message** in every single ES record.

I tried using the *overwrite* as such under the *match* but still no luck:

```
overwrite => [ "message" ]
```

All in all what I need to see in my indice are the messages (app_message, response_message from the above match), which should match the above two conditions. Where as now, all the lines are getting indexed.

Is it possible do something like this? Or does **Logstash** index all of them by default?

Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexing only the lines you want is pretty straightforward.

By default, if `grok` fails to match anything it will add the tag `_grokparsefailure`.

Now what you want to do is check for that tag and then use the drop filter.

```
if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
  drop { }
}
```

[sysadmin1138](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388165/sysadmin1138) mentioned that you can select between different grok filters by adding `tag_on_failure => ['_INFOFailure' ]`

---

For your sencond question you can simply remove the field. Every filter has a `remove_field` option but I use the `mutate` filter to indicate that I am manipulating the message.

```
mutate {
  remove_field => ["message"]
}
```

Comment: And, if you have multiple grok statements, you can have that specific grok statement tag parse-failures with a specific tag. This is done like: `tag_on_failure => ['_INFOFailure' ]`

Comment: Thank you @Fairy and *sysadmin1138* for the pointing me in the right direction. :)